# What is the best way to extract all <a href="#">#</a> tags from a string

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm currently working with the CakePHP 3.x framework and for a new function I need to extract all `<a hrefs="#">#</a>` from a text, but I don't know the best way to do this.

Example:

```
// String wich contains <a hrefs="#">#</a> tags 
$string = "This is a small <a href="#">text</a> to create a <a href="#">example</a>"; 

// output
Link 1: <a href="#">text</a>
Link 2: <a href="#">example</a>
```

Comment: http://php.net/dom + xpath: `//a`.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with CakePHP. Please pick the appropriate tags...

Comment: DOM isn't possible for me because I can't install it on the server at this time. Did you have some other ways to get all the hrefs?